Add your own classes to the rendered markdown in Spatie laravel markdown
Am trying to use the Spatie laravel markdown package to create a blogging site. And I have kind of got it working. I am saving my markdown in a field in a posts table. The markdown renders in my blade view
div class="md:w-2/3  max-w-none text-white over">
        <x-markdown>
                {!! $post->content !!}
</x-markdown>
</div>

However I am unable to figure out how to inject some extra classes into the rendered markdown. Specifically i would like to add some padding and margins around the fenced code i have in my saved markdown
Any help will be appreicatied
